# Calculating new and returning Customer Per Month in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am using this formula to calculate the new and returning customers per month.

```
=COUNTIFS(neww,1,date,">="&BH2,date,"<="&EOMONTH(BH2,0))
```

[image]

Im getting 0 everywhere. What I am doing wrong here?

This is the excel file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PbB1XdRM539gyMvmclXUW8lXncDNJRzI/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109497970689912563119&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `EOMONTH()` expects a number in it's 1st parameter. You currently use a text. Therefor you could try:

```
=COUNTIFS(neww,1,date,">="&--("1-"&BH2),date,"<="&EOMONTH(--("1-"&BH2),0))
```

[image]

Comment: How did you convert the date to this format ''1/1/2022'' ? in column F?

Comment: That was a simple click in your GS-data under 'Format>Number>Date' notation. Just so to make the formula work, but I had no problem with your input in Excel itself @SimonGIS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your month column is actually string values. So, try wildcards in `Countif()` criteria. Try-

```
=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$99,"*"&BH2,$G$2:$G$99,1)
```